# Wrapping output into string with same length as output

Tags: python, text, printing

If I have such string:

```
link = '|link: http://www.facebook.com |'
```

how can I print such string with arrows?:

```
|link: http://www.facebook.com |
<=============================>
```

The length of arrow string is equal to len(link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "<{}>".format('='*(len(link)-2))
```